# Copy HttpRequest and make another call with same Headers/Cookies/All so cookie wont expire

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have 2 services up running, A and B.

When i Call `A/perform`, A calls `B/perform` using owin shared cookies.

My Owin config is the following:

```
 public static void ConfigureAuth(this IAppBuilder app)
  {
     var keysFolderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP"), @"Kneat\KneatKeyRing");
     DirectoryInfo directoryInfoKeysFolder;
     if (!Directory.Exists(keysFolderPath))
     {
        directoryInfoKeysFolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(keysFolderPath);
     }
     else
     {
        directoryInfoKeysFolder = new DirectoryInfo(keysFolderPath);
     }
     var protectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(directoryInfoKeysFolder);

     app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
     {
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        CookieName = ".AspNet.SharedCookie",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
       // SlidingExpiration = true,
        // ExpireTimeSpan = ExpireTimeSpan,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000*10),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
        {
           OnApplyRedirect = context =>
           {
              if (!IsAjaxRequest(context.Request) && !IsApiRequest(context.Request))
              {
                 context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
              }
           }
        },
        TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
           new DataProtectorShim(protectionProvider
              .CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                               "Cookies",
                               "v2")))
     });
  }
```

If i set the timeout time in owin for 10 seconds (as it shows) and login into A and use that same cookie to make requests to B, that cookie should be updated so it wont expire, however thats not happening. Ive tryed copyng the cookies in the A to B request as follows:

```
public async Task<string> Perform()
  {

     var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

     using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
     using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
     {
        foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies)
        {
           cookieContainer.Add(new Uri($"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Host}"), new Cookie(cookie.Key, cookie.Value));
        }
        var performed = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost.kneat.org/B/perform");
        return performed ;
     }
  }
```

Is there any way i can copy the request somehow in order the same cookie its still valid in both contexts ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Are you trying to do something [like this cookie sharing scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing?tabs=aspnetcore2x)?

Comment: yup i followed that exact guide.

Comment: If you have gotten the sample code they provide working, I'd check how your code is different from their samples. I don't have much time to look into the details of the samples today but it seems like something got "lost in translation" in your application code :)